# Java method arrangement, runtime error

Tags: java, runtime

I've written a program that displays tokens dropped into a board depending on the user's selection of which column to drop it in. I'm getting a runtime error

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsExcepti… String index out of range: 42
    at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
    at A1Program.extractRow(A1Program.java:83)
    at A1Program.start(A1Program.java:19)
    at A1Application.main(A1Application.java:11…
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv… Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.inv… Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl… Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at edu.rice.cs.drjava.model.compiler.JavacC…
```

when I run the program, and I'm a bit lost as to where I might have gone wrong.

My code is:

```
public class A1Program {

    public void start() {

        String inputString = "XOXOXOO X XXO X OXO ";
        boolean gameOver = false;

        String tokens = inputString;

        while (!gameOver) {
            int column = columnResult();
            tokens = enterToken("X", tokens, column); 
            System.out.println(tokens);
            displayBoard(extractRow(5, tokens));
            displayBoard(extractRow(4, tokens));
            displayBoard(extractRow(3, tokens));
            displayBoard(extractRow(2, tokens));
            displayBoard(extractRow(1, tokens));
            displayBoard(extractRow(0, tokens));
            System.out.println("---------------");
        }
    }

    private int columnResult(){
        System.out.println("Enter column for X:");
        String keyInput = Keyboard.readInput();
        int column1 = Integer.parseInt(keyInput);
        return column1;
    }
    private String enterToken(String tokenSymbol, String inputString, int column){
        String columnEdit = inputString.substring(column*6-6,column*… 

        String columnEdit1 = columnEdit.trim();
        String columnEdit2 = columnEdit1+tokenSymbol+" ";
        String columnEdit3 = columnEdit2.substring(0,6);
        String start = inputString.substring(0,column*6-6);
        String end = inputString.substring(column*6);

        System.out.println(start);
        return start+tokenSymbol+end;
    }

    private String extractRow(int row, String tokens) {
        String rowString1 = tokens.substring(row, row + 1);
        String rowString2 = tokens.substring(row + 6, row + 7);
        String rowString3 = tokens.substring(row + 12, row + 13);
        String rowString4 = tokens.substring(row + 18, row + 19);
        String rowString5 = tokens.substring(row + 24, row + 25);
        String rowString6 = tokens.substring(row + 30, row + 31);
        String rowString7 = tokens.substring(row + 36, row + 37);

        return "|" + rowString1 + "|" + rowString2 + "|"
                + rowString3 + "|" + rowString4 + "|" + rowString5
                + "|" + rowString6 + "|" + rowString7 + "|";

    }

    private void displayBoard(String extractRow) {

        System.out.println(extractRow);

    }
}
```

Comment: Others will be more likely to assist you if you present your question in a more readable format (properly indented code, formatted stack traces, etc.).

Comment: The exception clearly states your issue lies in a call to the `String.substring()` method. You are going past the length of a string.

Comment: Did u try using a debugger to see what is going wrong?

Comment: What's the `String columnEdit = inputString.substring(column*6-6,column*…` supposed to do?

Comment: It's not like that in my code.. it really says "String columnEdit = inputString.substring(column*6-6,column*6);". Must be stackoverflow formatting it improperly.

Comment: Added homework tag. I know this is homework because there's been about 10 questions recently on this same content.

Answer (score 0):

The following line from the trace: `java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)` indicates that the problem is in `tokens.substring()`

It is because the length of tokens is less the substring that you're trying to extract. You can print the length of tokens and check for yourself

Comment: The code changes `tokens` midway- `tokens = enterToken("X", tokens, column);`, so `tokens` is not exactly `"XOXOXOO X XXO X OXO"` but is still shorter than the substring parameters.

Comment: Ah, my browser removed the intended spaces from that string. 

The string has 42 characters, and just in case, I added 10 more spaces to make it well over the 42 character limit. But it still gives me a similar error:

java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1
 at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
 at A1Program.extractRow(A1Program.java:78)
 at A1Program.start(A1Program.java:24)
 at A1Application.main(A1Application.java:11)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
 at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
 }